# How to find out which consumer picking the request (Implemented multiple consumer concept in the ActiveMQ Artemis)

Tags: activemq-artemis, consumer

We have 3 producers and 3 consumers. While producers are sending messages to the queue the messages are processed by one of the consumers. We are trying to identify which producers are sending the messages, but we couldn't determine which consumers are processing them.

Help me the find out which consumers taken the taken and processing how to check this things from the ActiveMQ Artemis web console.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to track which consumer got which message? One of the benefits of de-coupled, asynchronous messaging is that you don't need to care what consumers get what messages.

Comment: We have a logic issue on the consumer, One consumer taking time to complete the task for that we need to identify which consumer taken more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broker doesn't hold on to historical data about which message was acknowledged by which consumer. However, you can enable logging which will give you these details in real time.

First, configure the `LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin` in `broker.xml` as follow:

```xml
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
```

Second, enabled `DEBUG` logging for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl` in `log4j2.properties`, e.g.:

```
logger.artemis_utils.name=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl
logger.artemis_utils.level=DEBUG
```

Comment: Yes this will help to identify the consumer thank you for the support this is very useful for me

Comment: yes Justin this is working fine for me debugging the issue which consumer picking the message
Thank you

Comment: Yes this anwser is helpful but i don't know how to mark please guide me to mark this